# How can I convert labels of a guide into a custom format?

Tags: r, plot, gradient

I have this code to build my plot

here is merged1.data

> structure(list(time = c(1391525413022, 1391525438998, 1391525440903, 
>   1391525446466, 1391525451770, 1391525456050, 1391525472635, 1391525489437, 
>   1391525502903, 1391525512793, 1391525524136, 1391525549132, 1391525562656, 
>   1391525570842, 1391525578937, 1391525603513, 1391525858760, 1391525988388, 
>   1391525991792, 1391526065759), time_print = structure(c(1391525413, 
>   1391525438, 1391525440, 1391525446, 1391525451, 1391525456, 1391525472, 
>   1391525489, 1391525502, 1391525512, 1391525524, 1391525549, 1391525562, 
>   1391525570, 1391525578, 1391525603, 1391525858, 1391525988, 1391525991, 
>   1391526065), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), elapsed = c(2016, 
>   1830, 2494, 2717, 2837, 1093, 1216, 2536, 2656, 2416, 2093, 2684, 
>   1878, 2808, 2294, 1179, 1291, 1166, 1244, 1039), threads = c(7, 
>   7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), version = structure(c(1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "025.00", class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
>   "time_print", "elapsed", "threads", "version"), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -20L), class = "data.frame")

here  is merged2.data

> structure(list(time = c(1391525413022, 1391525438998, 1391525440903, 
>   1391525446466, 1391525451770, 1391525456050, 1391525472635, 1391525489437, 
>   1391525502903, 1391525512793, 1391525524136, 1391525549132, 1391525562656, 
>   1391525570842, 1391525578937, 1391525603513, 1391525858760, 1391525988388, 
>   1391525991792, 1391526065759), time_print = structure(c(1391525413, 
>   1391525438, 1391525440, 1391525446, 1391525451, 1391525456, 1391525472, 
>   1391525489, 1391525502, 1391525512, 1391525524, 1391525549, 1391525562, 
>   1391525570, 1391525578, 1391525603, 1391525858, 1391525988, 1391525991, 
>   1391526065), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), elapsed = c(2016, 
>   1830, 2494, 2717, 2837, 1093, 1216, 2536, 2656, 2416, 2093, 2684, 
>   1878, 2808, 2294, 1179, 1291, 1166, 1244, 1039), threads = c(6, 
>   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), version = structure(c(1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "025.02", class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
>   "time_print", "elapsed", "threads", "version"), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -20L), class = "data.frame")

and the plot function

```
combined_plot <- ggplot(merged1.data, aes(x=threads, y=elapsed)) + 
                     geom_point(aes(size = elapsed,shape=version, colour=time), show_guide = TRUE) +
                     scale_size(guide="none") + 
                     scale_color_gradient(high = "black", low="green", name="Time") + 
                     geom_point(data=merged2.data, aes(size = elapsed, shape=version, colour=time), show_guide = TRUE) + 
                     scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,17), name="Versions")
```

Here I'm plotting response time vs current amount of threads running and gradient supposed to be a third dimention on the 2d screen just to indicate where we started capturing data and where we're ended to do this.

`time` is a timestamp like `1.391525e+12` (as it shows in the console) and when I compute gradient color with this values, it looks ugly on the legend.

So what I want is to compute gradient color depending on this list of numeric values but to show them converted (for instance, into a human-readable date/time) as labels on my gradient legend. Now this looks like on the picture below:

[image: elapsed versus threads]

Comment: Have you tried converting your timestamps into a POSIXct variable?

Comment: @Roland well yes, I've tried but I cannot use gradient with non numeric values , the problem is that list of values is very huge so this is not like 10 snapshots of a data to be representable on discrete legend...

Comment: @Roland I somehow must point data for functionality that prints that labels on picture but i dont know how...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `dput(merged1.data)`.

Comment: @Roland, thank you very much for your help, i linked the structure info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a formatter function as [shown](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/#tick-mark-label-text-formatters) in the Cookbook:

```
datetime_formatter <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXct(x/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")  
  lab <- format(x, "%d.%m. %H:%M:%S")
  lab
}

combined_plot <- ggplot(merged1.data, aes(x=threads, y=elapsed)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = elapsed,shape=version, colour=time), show_guide = TRUE) +
  scale_size(guide="none") + 
  scale_color_gradient(high = "black", low="green", name="Time", label=datetime_formatter) + 
  geom_point(data=merged2.data, aes(size = elapsed, shape=version, colour=time), show_guide = TRUE) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,17), name="Versions")

print(combined_plot)
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is what I believe is a better way to present this data (assuming your real data is less redundant than what you show here).

```
DF <- rbind(merged1.data, merged2.data)
combined_plot <- ggplot(DF, 
                        aes(x=time_print, y=elapsed, colour=factor(threads), 
                            shape=version)) + 
                    geom_point(size=5)
print(combined_plot)
```

[image]

However, it's difficult to recommend alternatives without having all the facts.

Comment: This is simply awesome, thank you very much, @Roland, you're a pro

Comment: And a little side question, do you think that this form of a plot are efficient for representing the actual view by the process ? Or it's ugly way to do this ? How would you do that by yourself ?